# What Meaning of 'in which' here

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, vocabulary

What does ‘in which’ mean in the following context?

> **Window size (window=10000 B):** receiver tells about his buffer capacity in which he has to store messages from the sender.

Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tcp-connection-establishment/?ref=lbp

Comment: The receiver tells about his buffer capacity **that** [in which] he has to store messages from the sender **in**.

Comment: "In which he has to store messages from the sender" is a relative clause  modifying "buffer capacity". "Which" functions as object of "in", and has "buffer capacity" as its antecedent. We understand he has to store messages from the sender in his buffer capacity.

Comment: I think it is badly written, but intelligible.  He stores messages in a buffer which has a certain capacity; he doesn't store messages in the capacity, which is a property of the buffer. It's like saying *The farmer spoke about his silo capacity in which he has to store grain.* It would be better to say *The farmer spoke about the capacity of the silo in which he has to store grain.*

Answer (score 1):

> ... about his buffer capacity in which he has to store messages from the sender.

The example is indeed unclear.
We store messages in the buffer rather than the capacity.  My suggestion is

> ... about **the capacity of his buffer** in which he has to store messages from the sender.

The relative pronoun *which* has *buffer* as its antecedent, and this is now made clear.

In the original example, *buffer* is made an attribute noun, and *capacity* appears to be the antecedent, hence the sentence is unclear.

Comment: Yes, and tells about is wrong too.